# C++ array greater than 0 print code

Tags: c++

I am having issues with this block of code:

```
    else if (mineOrRefine == "refine" || mineOrRefine == "Refine")
    if (StoneInventory[0] == 0)
        cout << "You currently have no stone!" << endl;
int a = StoneInventory[0];
    else if (a == >1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Bloody. You're more likely to get help if you mention any errors you're getting and what your code is trying to achieve. As it is your question is too barebones so I'm flagging to close.

Comment: You may want to use `std::tolower` or `std::toupper` and `std::transform`, so you don't have to compare to these also: "rEfine", "reFine", "reFINE", etc.  Convert to all upper or all lower case before comparison.

Comment: Your `else if` doesn't match the previous `if` due to `int a = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not saying what the problem is, but I can all but guarantee it has to do with a lack of braces. Put your if and else blocks into braces, even when it's just one line, to reduce confusion.  I'm not going to get into a debate about whether to put braces around a single expression following if/else in general, only that, in your case, the lack of braces is confusing you, so put them in.

Comment: What do you mean add braces? I have all the braces added. It's saying that it's expecting a statement.

Comment: @Bloody there are no braces in your code. `()` are parenthesis, `{}` are braces. You have none. Put in the braces in the right places, and that will either make the problem clearer, or outright solve it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of ( a== >1), use (a>=1) or (a>0)
also, any 'if' statement with more than one line of code should use curly braces. ie: `if (x) { /* code */ }`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out rn.

Comment: Hm, nope. It is still telling me that it is expecting an expression. I will just leave this out for now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: this error is likely because your braces still arent proper. if, else if, else -> they all need braces enclosing the code within them.

Comment: I will look over it. I need to setup some other stuff first. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're lost in the `if`s, and you really need to add curly braces to see what's going on. The code amounts to this:

```
if (something_you_havent_shown)
    {
    // something else you haven't shown
    }
else if (mineOrRefine == "refine" || mineOrRefine == "Refine)
    {
    if (StoneInventory[0] == 0)
        {
        std::cout << "You currently have no stone!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
int a = StoneInventory[0];
else if (something_you_say_youve_changed_since_asking_the_question)
```

The `else` in that last line doesn't go with any preceding `if` -- they've all finished, because each one applies only to the next line.